# How to understand "maximal ", bounded", and "complete" for solutions of a (hybrid) dynamical system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory

I am trying to read some text books about hybrid dynamical system, in which maximal solution, bounded solution, and complete solution are mentioned frequently.

The following passage is a description about the solutions of hybrid dynamical system from the article I am reading. I cannot understand it well.

"The solution x to a hybrid system is nontrivial if dom x
contains at least one point different from (0,0) ; maximal
if it cannot be extended, that is, the hybrid system has
no solution x' whose domain dom x' contains dom x as
a proper subset and such that x' agrees with x on dom x;
and complete if dom x is unbounded. Every complete
solution is maximal."

How to understand "maximal ", bounded", and "complete" for solutions of a (hybrid) dynamical system? I hope the answers can be precise and easy to understand for a non-mathematics student.

Comment: "Every complete solution is maximal." Not with these definitions.